# HTML5 EventSource raises error even though request is 200 OK

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've got the following JS-Snippet:

```
  var source = new EventSource( "http://localhost:8081/resources" );
  source.onmessage = function() {
    console.log( "Event received!" );
  };

  source.onerror = function( error ) {
    console.log( "Eventsource error" );
    console.log( error );
  };

  source.open = function() {
    console.log( "Eventsource open" );
  };
```

My server is emitting a simple test event once. In chrome's network tab I can see the event coming in as `text/event-stream` and a status code of `200`. Nevertheless, my `onmessage` callback doesn't get called. Instead, I get the `onerror` callback, but with not a lot of useful error information.

Another thing that puzzles me, is the fact that chrome seems to re-request the event every 3 seconds or so. I get log output on the server suggesting that and also the error event is occuring every 3 seconds.

If it helps, all of this is taking place in a CORS scenario.

The same is happening in Firefox, only I can't see the requests in the network tab, I think Firefox just doesn't display SSE-Events there.